# Test Suite Commands cannot be recognized by Google Home device

Tags: test-suite

When using Test Suite for my Google Home instance, the provided command cannot be recognized by Google Home device, it always end with a Google Search result. If using the command in different format, it works correctly. It currently is a blocker for my instance to get released, how could I solve this issue?

Comment: When you say test commands can not be recognized - are you getting an error?

Comment: For example, the utterance/command "[Modes] Ok Google. Change the mode to home on the Kitchen" always gets "FAIL". And error log is "Expected state to include: {"currentModeSettings":{"mode":"Home"}}, actual state: {"online":true,"currentModeSettings":{"mode":"home"}}: expected false to be true".
But if I use utterance "OK Google, set the kitchen mode to home", it can be recognized and processed correctly.